# When to clear textbox XML to avoid flagging as XSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss

I have an ASP.NET application that will display a Dataset's XML in a textbox when a button is clicked.

Clicking the button again should rerun the request, but before this can happen I get an error saying 'A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (`txtXML="<NewDataSet>` ...)'  Obviously, the angle brackets are being interpreted as a potential cross-site scripting attack.

I tried clearing the textbox text in the button click event handler and the Page_Load() method, but these seem to be too late.

Is there another event I can handle that will allow me to clear the text early enough in the request-handling process?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear textbox in client side using javascript before sending unnecessary data back to server:

On button: `<asp:Button OnClientClick="document.getElementById(...).value = '';" .... />`
or something similar.

But this still looks like a hack. If you intent only to display the text, why aren't you using more appropriate control for that?

Comment: I'm just displaying the XML in a textbox as a test, not for use on a production server, so security is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

Yeah, this is ASP.NET's utterly bogus attempt to mitigate cross-site-scripting vulnerabilities. You can turn it off by adding:

```
ValidateRequest="false"
```

to the @Page directive at the top of your template.

Naturally you should be sure you're properly HTML-escaping any incoming `<&` symbols before you spit them into a textarea, otherwise you'd be vulnerable to XSS attacks. But that's the case even with ValidateRequest turned on; it buys you only an obfuscation and illusion of security.

Shame on MS for turning this wrong-headed application-breaking feature on by default.

If you don't need the txtXML to be submitted with the next request, try moving it out of the form/removing the name attribute.